# javascript TypeError: window.document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

I use the following code to get links from a page but when I try to write it to an array I get the error message. I tested it with Firebug-Console.

```
function getElements() {
var mylinks = new Array();

    for (var i=1;i<50;i++){
    var linkID = "websiteLink" + i;
    var element = window.document.getElementById(linkID).innerHTML;
    mylinks[i-1] = element;
     }
    //alert(mylinks[0]);

}

getElements();
```

Comment: That code looks correct, at what point does it say it's null?  Are you certain you have IDs websiteLink1 - websiteLink50?  A jsFiddle might prove helpful here.  Also, I think  `document.getElementsByTagName("href")` would be a little more maintainable; but it would get all links on your page so it might still require a loop to remove what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
function getElements() {
var mylinks = new Array();

    for (var i=1;i<50;i++){
    var linkID = "websiteLink" + i;
    var element = document.getElementById(linkID);
    if(element !== null)mylinks.push(element.innerHTML);
     }
    //alert(mylinks[0]);

}

getElements();
```

you are trying to access the value property of the innerHTML property of a Dom node

I would suggest using jquery here to get a more failsafe/cross browser result.
Add 'websiteLink' as a class to all the links you want to grab.

```
var mylinks = [];
$('.websiteLink').each(function(idx,item){
mylinks.push($(item).html());
});
alert(mylinks);
```

Comment: Here I get: TypeError: element is null

Comment: I tried element.value, element.href and element.innerHTML. Strange thing is that if I alert element.innerHTML I see the link but for some reason it cannot be assigend to array.

Comment: ah ok you want the contents of the dom nodes not just the href property.
edited again

this should work now for you.
In your first example it didn't work because you are assigning the .innerHTML property (which is a String, containing what you want) of a dom node to the variable element and then you try to access the value property of element but Strings don't have value properties

Comment: @John What happens if you remove `.innerHTML` and just point to the node.  Does that much work?

Comment: you can use .outerHTML instead of .innerHTML to get a string including the outer tags

Comment: Now I get an empty alert window and this error message: undefined

Comment: If I don't assign innerHTML or outerHTML I get a lot of hrefs but this is not the information I want. I want the content of the hrefs.

Comment: are you doing the alert inside the "getElements" function closure?
remember as you defining "mylinks" as a local variable inside "getElements" its only available in there. You have to move "var mylinks = new Array();" somewhere before the function definition "getElements" to make it accessible globally from e.g. firebug

Comment: if there is at least one node with the id ["websiteLink1" ... "websiteLink50"] you may not get "error message: undefined" on "alert(mylinks[0])". But you may also want to replace "alert(mylinks[0])" with "console.log(mylinks)" to get rid of the annoying debug popups.

Comment: maybe its because you didn't update "mylinks[i-1] = element;" to this "mylinks.push(element.innerHTML);"